# How to target multi SQL Server editions

Tags: sql-server, wmi, smo

I have built a Windows application to backup databases.

I downloaded SQL Server 2012, I want to add `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement.dll` DLLs as references to my project to connect with SQL Server 2016 and/or SQL Server 2014. What do I need to deploy in order to achieve that?

When I added references that are not related to the same SQL Server edition I got the error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.WmiEnum, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need the **newest** version of the DLL's.

If you have the **SQL Server 2012** version, you can connect to any server with a version up to 2012 - SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012.

If you want to connect to SQL Server 2014 and 2016, too, you **must use** the SQL Server 2016 versions of those SMO DLL's

Comment: I actually need to add a DLL wich is compatable with all SQL Server versions, and when I used SQL Server 2016 DLLs , I also got the error above , because I have used DLLs that are not compatable eith SQL Server version that have been downloaded (SQL Server 2012)

Comment: @T.Hajjar: as I said - if you want to target **all** versions 2008, 2008R2, 2012, 2014, 2016  then you need the 2016 DLL's. The error just says it's **missing** one of the DLL's - so you probably didn't add **all** relevant DLL's ....

Comment: but every time I tried to add a DLL , it asks me for another one which is already exist in the working directory of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, remember that you SMO is installed with SQL Server version that you have installed in your machine, you have to download the last version to be compatible with all previous version.

[Download Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676)